# Что такое точка входа в SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, терминология, fastapi

Изучаю FastAPI по курсу. Автор многие вещи не договаривает.

Есть кусок кода:

```
DATABASE_URL = f"postgresql+asyncpg://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASS}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}"

.....
engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL)
async_session_maker = async_sessionmaker(engine, expire_on_commit=False)
```

Автор говорит, что engine - это точка входа sql-алхимии в наше приложение. И что далее с помощью этого движка мы создаём сессии,чтобы можно было работать с базой данных.

Не пойму что значит

> engine это **точка входа** sql алхимии в наше
> приложение.

Что за точка входа?

И

> "с помощью этого **движка** мы создаём сессии"

Что значит движок в этом контексте?

Comment: "Что за точка входа?" - это фигура речи. "Что значит движок в этом контексте?" - engine == двигатель == "движок". Это служебный объект, через который можно, например, создавать сессии, а через сессии выполнять запросы. Именно так и нужно понимать. Движком/engine его решил назвать автор алхимии. Какого-то сакрального смысла в этом названии нет.